# Problem referring to R globally

Tags: android

I'm trying to declare some final Strings for using as keys later, but I keep getting a null pointer exception.

```
private final String KEY = getString(R.string.key);
```

This is declared at the top of my activity, before onCreate(). Does the problem stem from referring to R in the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that you cannot access the `getString(..)` there.
Why dont you just save the int value?

```
private static final int KEY = R.string.key
```

and than where you need it call the `yourContext.getString(KEY);`

:)

Comment: Great idea. I can't hit answered for another 7 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

These initializers will be called when the object is constructed, which may be before it has a valid context.

Don't call getString() before onCreate().  You won't be able to have the strings final, though.